# Lightswitch Inventory App

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am building an inventory logging system in LightSwitch and the requirements specify that each line should show the ending balance after the change like a check register.

I have 3 tables imported from a SQL Server.
Products : used to specify product info

> ( ID, Name, Description, etc..)

InventoryLogs : used to log each change to inventory

> ( ID, DateTimeStamp, Person, ProductID, QuantityAdded, QuantityRemoved, EndingBalance)

InventoryCurrent : used to keep current inventory quantities to reduce calculation overhead

> ( ID, ProductID, Quantity )

I setup the InventoryLogs table as a screen that users can enter their changes to the inventory.  I want the EndingBalance field to be automatically calculated from by getting the value from the InventoryCurrent table and adding/subtracting the change, but I can not seem to figure out how to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I needed.  I was able to manipulate the save event to correct, and set the values.